# Trigger something only after Resend Request is satisfied if exists with QuickFIX/J

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, reconnect, quickfixj

Our system generates some messages (unsolicited cancel for example) it needs to send to the other party after a disconnect/connection lost, as soon as the connection recovers.

The problem is that we trigger sending those in `onLogon()`, but if there's a Resend Request that's too early and we had problems (maybe just because of how is implemented on the other end) when we had too many messages to send (hundreds).

I'm aware that `ResendRequest` may not come and it is impossible to figure that out without simply waiting, but what would be the best approach for us using QuickFIX/J to send our messages as soon as possible but after sequence numbers are synchronized?

EDIT: I'm trying to solve this using FIX 4.2. FIX 4.4 actually introduced http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/tagNum_789.html which would solve my problem (as long as the other party sends this optional tag too).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My 10 cents is it sounds like you're trying to treat 2 scenarios in 1 go, and that's difficult. Do 1 thing at a time. For example, if it's your network that causes you to disconnect, before your client knows you've disconnected, your clients will send resend requests, right? Meanwhile, if a client disconnects but you don't then when they reconnect you gap fill. You've got to look carefully at the scenarios. Yes, a resend request may not come at all, it all depends how the client configures things their side. Maybe, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559025/fix-client-asked-for-gapfill-but-i-want-to-send-a-sequencereset-instead-what-s) you want to send sequence resets because actually, the messages you're trying to send are quotes, right? I mean, what kind of messages are you trying to resend after a disco?

Comment: I don't believe I actually try to solve two scenarios at once unless I don't actually understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I don't try to solve the disconnect thing which can happen because of network but at that time the lost message (which we may be required to resend) could be just a Heartbeat or even a FILL which we'll definitely need to resend. Now, while we are disconnected we cancel some orders on our side (cause we don't want to get them filled while the other side has no control) and we need to send those unsolicited cancels as soon as the connection is back.

Comment: What I'm looking for actually is a solution to cover this corner case with minimum impact on the 99% of cases when there's no lost messages and no ResendRequest. PS: see my new edit on the question regarding FIX version too.

Comment: ok so if we take the important point that you must resend cancel messages just as soon as possible (otherwise you may obtain a position in the market you never know about) then I would work out with your cpty to Cancel On Disconnect. I mean, what if the network doesn't come back for several minutes or even hours? So your cpty must have a policy here, because presumably they have other FIX connections besides yours?

Comment: ok, then if we take the important point of communicating fill messages. Hmm, which way around is this? is it you executing a fill for a client? Let's say it is, and your cancel on disconnect policy cancels all client orders if a client discos, but let's say in a race condition an order fills but you can't send it because of a disco. Then, you have to manage that by email / phone. I mean you have to escalate because, like above, the network might not come back for minutes or hours ! So you need to be able to go manual. I suggest giving it x seconds (agreed with client) before a phone call.

Comment: Both (us sending fills and unsolicited cancels generated while connection is down) are valid scenarios for us at the same time, even if just corner cases. I agree with what you say regarding that connection may never recover and we do have manual procedures in place but the specs are standing for a connection that recovers immediately before a person can even notice that. For those short hiccups I was trying to find some better approach but, especially after seeing that FIX 4.4 kind of addressed this issue, I doubt I'd find something better than just waiting a couple of seconds (with FIX 4.2).

Comment: The way to do it is have a policy so that on a disconnect then every active order type is cancelled. However, other order types may not be (for example limit orders etc) and I can't see a way around managing those other than manually. Meanwhile if there is a disco and a race condition so there is a fill, whatever happens you're probably going to have to send the message once the connection is back up. But you have to watch out for duplicates of data you may have transferred by voice... This kind of thing is some of what your monitoring sub-system is for!